# Heroku H14 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I don't know what happened. I changed one typo in some static html and pushed it back up and it broke. I am receiving this error in my heroku logs:

```
2014-02-10T23:36:07.218200+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=www.lagunasmostcreative.com request_id=98727434-1833-46d7-ad34-fcffa0d85db0 fwd="108.245.9.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-10T23:33:17.447160+00:00 heroku[run.6806]: State changed from up to complete
2014-02-10T23:35:28.492706+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=www.lagunasmostcreative.com request_id=85185289-5e06-4ba4-ba7b-f8037601a385 fwd="108.245.9.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-02-10T23:44:10.934561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=www.lagunasmostcreative.com request_id=1c51a16d-e2f4-4c0e-9e5c-2d8292e0f0a4 fwd="108.245.9.197" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

I am still using the rails gem `pg`
and here is my `database.yml`:

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: Best\ of\ Laguna_development
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: Best\ of\ Laguna_test
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: Best\ of\ Laguna_production
  pool: 5
  username:
  password:
```

Let me know if you need me to post anything else.  This is mind boggling! I've researched a ton of stuff about procfiles and it should be using webrick.

Comment: Have you tried to run `heroku ps:scale web=1` ?

Comment: Yup, I get this. Scaling dynos... failed
 !    No such process type web defined in Procfile.  However, I'm using webrick, so I shouldn't need a procfile.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, just added the 'unicorn' gem and created a procfile.  Oh well...